# R reshape wide data to long

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have the following data frame, which gives a logical response for a number of criteria arranged across columns:

```
    structure(list(Householdref = c("003015002024001", "003016003006001", 
"003016004013001", "003016006002001", "003017003009002", "003017003009003", 
"003017003009004", "003017003037001", "003017003049001", "003070001026001", 
"003070003042001", "003070005002001", "003070005021001", "003070009005001", 
"003071002055001", "003071003037001", "003072003029001", "003072006002001", 
"003072006018001"), B5_Glass = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), B5_Glass.bottles = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), B5_Paper.cardboard = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), B5_Metal.cans = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), B5_Food.biodegradables = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), B5_Plastic.polybags = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), B5_Plastic.bottles.containers = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), B5_other = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("Householdref", 
"B5_Glass", "B5_Glass.bottles", "B5_Paper.cardboard", "B5_Metal.cans", 
"B5_Food.biodegradables", "B5_Plastic.polybags", "B5_Plastic.bottles.containers", 
"B5_other"), row.names = c("13", "21", "25", "29", "55", "56", 
"57", "60", "61", "69", "76", "81", "83", "90", "101", "108", 
"120", "125", "127"), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to reshape this data so that I have just three columns: `Householdref, TRUE and FALSE` so that the names of columns now appear in the TRUE or FALSE columns so that there would be multiple rows for each `Householdref`.

I have been experimenting with `reshape()` as follows:

```
reshape(ar_waste_sep, direction="long", varying=2:9, sep=c("_"))
```

but end up with this:

```
                                 Householdref                       time  B5   id
1.Glass                       003015002024001                      Glass FALSE  1
2.Glass                       003016003006001                      Glass FALSE  2
3.Glass                       003016004013001                      Glass FALSE  3
4.Glass                       003016006002001                      Glass FALSE  4
5.Glass                       003017003009002                      Glass FALSE  5
6.Glass                       003017003009003                      Glass FALSE  6
7.Glass                       003017003009004                      Glass FALSE  7
8.Glass                       003017003037001                      Glass FALSE  8
9.Glass                       003017003049001                      Glass FALSE  9
10.Glass                      003070001026001                      Glass FALSE 10
11.Glass                      003070003042001                      Glass FALSE 11
12.Glass                      003070005002001                      Glass FALSE 12
```

So as you can see not quite what I'm after. I have searched high and low for an example that would show me how to do what I want, and am sure it's not overly complicated, but am just going round in circle. Would someone know a quick and easy way to achieve what I want i.e. this:

```
  Householdref                       TRUE          FALSE
003015002024001                      Glass          NA
003015002024001                      Glass.bottles  NA
003015002024001                      NA             Paper.cardboard
003015002024001                      NA             Metal.cans
003015002024001                      NA             Plastic.bottles
003015002024001                      NA             Plastic
003017003009004                      GLass          NA
003017003009004                      NA             Glass.bottles                
003017003009004                      Paper.cardboardNA
```

thanks in advance,

Marty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2" to get (what I think) you want:

```
library(reshape2)
mydf <- melt(ar_waste_sep, id.vars="Householdref")
head(mydf)
#      Householdref variable value
# 1 003015002024001 B5_Glass FALSE
# 2 003016003006001 B5_Glass FALSE
# 3 003016004013001 B5_Glass FALSE
# 4 003016006002001 B5_Glass FALSE
# 5 003017003009002 B5_Glass FALSE
# 6 003017003009003 B5_Glass FALSE
out <- dcast(mydf, Householdref + variable ~ value, value.var="variable")
head(out)
#      Householdref               variable                  FALSE                TRUE
# 1 003015002024001               B5_Glass               B5_Glass                <NA>
# 2 003015002024001       B5_Glass.bottles                   <NA>    B5_Glass.bottles
# 3 003015002024001     B5_Paper.cardboard     B5_Paper.cardboard                <NA>
# 4 003015002024001          B5_Metal.cans                   <NA>       B5_Metal.cans
# 5 003015002024001 B5_Food.biodegradables B5_Food.biodegradables                <NA>
# 6 003015002024001    B5_Plastic.polybags                   <NA> B5_Plastic.polybags
```